# How to find sum of columns based on other column and group by month

Tags: mysql

I have the following table,

| Name | Correct Answers | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 10 | 2018-12-01 |
| John | 05 | 2018-12-05 |
| Liam | 80 | 2018-12-16 |
| Bern | 60 | 2018-12-04 |
| Liam | 25 | 2018-05-18 |
| John | 55 | 2016-12-01 |

Now for each month of 2018, I want to know what were the maximum and minimum correct answers, adding up each persons correct answers. The months that were not included should show up as NULL. And for ties it should show same value in both fields. So something like this,

| Month | Highest | Lowest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | NULL | NULL |
| 02 | NULL | NULL |
| 03 | NULL | NULL |
| 04 | NULL | NULL |
| 05 | 25 | 25 |
| 06 | NULL | NULL |
| 07 | NULL | NULL |
| 08 | NULL | NULL |
| 09 | NULL | NULL |
| 10 | NULL | NULL |
| 11 | NULL | NULL |
| 12 | 80 | 15 |

Is it possible to do something like this with a single large query or will I need to create views in between? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It needs a helper table with month values from 1 to 12, something like below:

```
with recursive 
months as (
  select 1 as month
  union 
  select month + 1
  from months 
  where month < 12
)
select m.month, max(t.answers), min(t.answers)
from months m
left join mytable t on m.month = month(t.`date`) and t.`date` between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'
group by m.month
```

or if not using `CTE`

```
select m.month, max(t.answers), min(t.answers)
from (
 select 1 as month
 union select 2
 union select 3
 union select 4
 union select 5
 union select 6
 union select 7
 union select 8
 union select 9
 union select 10
 union select 11
 union select 12
) m 
left join mytable t on m.month = month(t.`date`) and t.`date` between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'
group by m.month
```

Comment: I get an error that m.month is not a function

Comment: @Gops61 check this [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba22abc0863ced641784a10ce02cbe10)

Comment: How would I need to change the code if I want the the names who people who had the highest and lowest too?

Comment: @Gops61 join the table again, find the names by matching the year/month and the number of answers = min or max in the previous result set.

Comment: @Gops61 check this, it could help. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c147e8b0b88d382860f3b1593fc8828b